# if-and-else-if workflow

Tags: workflow, document-library, designer-workflow, approval-process, workflow-history

I am having a problem in my workflow.

Basically I have two variables (1) Business Unit and (2) Billing Information. I am creating a workflow that would hold the following:

1. If Business Unit = A AND if Billing information is X, Start Approval Process 1
2. If Business Unit = A AND if Billing information is Y, Start Approval Process 2.
3. If Business Unit = B AND if Billing information is X, Start Approval Process 3.
4. If Business Unit = B AND if Billing information is Y, Start Approval Process 4.
5. If Business Unit = C AND if Billing information is X, Start Approval Process 5.

and so on.. basically I have 12 business units and two billing information. Each combination should have a unique approval flow.

I've tried publishing the below but it told me that there's an error. Can anyone help please?

[image]

Comment: Which part is the error? When you try to publish, the part with an error should turn red.

Comment: if you made changes to the list, such as field choices, column names, etc, it may throw an error. My guess is the error is in one of the approval processes...look inside the very last "Approval (56)" workflow action

Comment: Thank you so much for answer, Erin. 

If I only have the approval flow up to the second "Else if" workflow (HR - PH Budget), I do not get a nerror. If I add the last "Approval (56)" though, I get an error:

Errors were found when compiling the workfow. The workflow files were saved but cannot be run. I ran the check errors button but nothing showed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating exactly the same workflow in another SPD site and I successfully published the workflow.

I sincerely believe that it is because of too many workflows have been made in the site where I posted the first workflow that had an error.

As you could see in my post above, when I try to create a workflow approval it shows that "Approval (56)", while in the site that I published it successfully, it only appears "Approval (11)" or near that number.

So, my question is, where do delete in SharePoint the previous records of approvals that I have?